# DIY Raspberry pi android phone with GSM Module?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gsm

I recently saw that people installing android os on raspberry pi. In my experience I know that raspberry pi can work with GSM Shields very well. So if I connect the GSM shield to the raspberry pi and install android will it work as a phone, will I be able to take calls from the raspberry pi? If not what changes I have to do inside the android os to take calls from the GSM shield?

Answer (score 0):

The best place for you to look is probably the Android Open Source Project documentation, where there are detailed instructions around Android builds and the low level system interfaces required on different devices:

- https://source.android.com

At a very high level, its worth remembering that a phone needs not just a GSM/3G etc radio interface to be integrated but also generally a speaker, a microphone and for most applications some sort of screen and input device, usually combined.